# Microsoft Word 2016 VSTO Add-In with Web Browser Control Issue

Tags: c#, vsto, word-addins

We are updating a legacy MS Word Add-In to run on Windows 10/MS Word 2016 from Windows 7/MS Word 2013.

There were no code changes made to the solution, we simply opened the solution which was previously developed in Visual Studio 2013 in Visual Studio 2017 and updated the .Net Framework to 4.6.

The Add-In provides a Windows Form that contains a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control that gives users the ability to preview other MS Word files that reside on a network share from within the Add-In without having to open another Word document.

In a nutshell:

1. The Add-In creates a local copy of the document (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp) as an .mht file.
2. Then the Add-In opens the file in the Form/WebBrowser control.

This all worked fine in our Windows 7/Word 2013 environment, but as we tested the new environment, we discovered that the WebBrowser control didn't want to open the .mht file for preview, instead, prompting us to download the file:

> "The file you are downloading cannot be opened by the default program.
>   It is either corrupted or it has an incorrect file type. As a security
>   precaution, it is recommended that you cancel the download"

- We've tested this on a different machine and received the same result and also created a simple stand alone application (Not an Add-In) and we were able to successfully open the .mht file, so I am suspecting there is a security or trust setting in Word 2016 that is preventing this from working as expected.
- The file associations for .mht are associated with Internet Explorer.
- I also tried to use Fiddler to see if it would capture any http traffic, however didn't see anything listed.
- Also ran PROCMON and have filtered the process down to the unique PID for the Word process involved which also includes the Add-In but don't see anything that indicates what the issue is.
- We also opened a ticket with Microsoft to see if they can assist and they were also to replicate the problem on their lab machines, although they haven't been able to tell us what the issue is yet.

I've seen a couple of similar issues here on Stack, but nothing that is helping yet.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just received a confirmation from Microsoft that this issue seems to be related to the C2R version of Office 2016.  The MSI version of Office 2016 exhibit this behavior. In the meantime, we've created a workaround that creates an .htm file and that seems to work.